# Truffle deploy contract Error: *** Deployment Failed *** "ERC20" -- already known

Tags: truffle

I'm using truffle to deploy [ERC20](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol) to [goerli test net](https://goerli.infura.io/v3/9aa3d95b3bc440fa88ea12eaa4456161), but I got this error:

```
Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"ERC201" -- already known.
```

My steps are:

1. Run migration by command: `truffle migrate --network goerli`
2. I waited too long time so I used `control + C` to exit the migration
3. I run the above migration command again and I got the error.

Node*: My truffle configuration is correct

Do you know how to fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

try running `truffle migrate --network goerli --reset` to replace previous deployments.

hope this works out for you